# VS Code does not see virtual environment variables in .env file when running django

Tags: django, windows, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, django-environ

I am trying to set up a postgres connection and use virtual environment variables for the first time.  I created a .env file and placed it in my settings folder but my database variable is missing each time I try to use manage.py runserver.  Is there a way to get this to run on windows?  Moving the .env file next to my virtual environment did not work either.  I also tried typing `set DATABASE_URL='postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/authors-live'` did not work either.

Folder Structure:

MASTERDJANGOWITHDOCKER

-env  (virtual environment folder)

-authors-src

--manage.py

--.env

--authors_api

---settings

----base.py

----.env

(both .env files are exactly the same)

**settings/base.py**

```
import environ

env = environ.Env()

ROOT_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent  # need three to get to manage.py level

# points django to where the apps are stored
APPS_DIR = ROOT_DIR / 'core_apps'

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

DATABASES = {
    'default': env.db('DATABASE_URL')
}
```

**.env file**

```
DATABASE_URL='postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/authors-live'
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY="django-insecure"
```

**error message**

```
...
File "C:\Python39\lib\os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DATABASE_URL'
...

File "C:\Users\...\authors-haven-api\authors-src\env\lib\site-packages\environ\environ.py", line 371, in get_value
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the DATABASE_URL environment variable
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the line:

`environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'settings', '.env'))`

I do not understand why the tutorial I found doesn't need it but my code does for some reason.